# Is there a way I can make the bot send an ephemeral message instead of an error in my console?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I get an error each [bot command still showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgek6.png) time I try to use my bot to ban my own bot. (which is normal and not really the point). What I don't like is that it sends an error into my console and the command (on discord) still shows up, even if its not banned and gives me an error in my vsc console. is there a way that when there's an error, the bot simply does an
ephemeral message to the person who did the command saying "There was an error, try later"

here's my code:

```js
     if (interaction.commandName === "ban") {
            const target = interaction.options.getMember('target');
            const reasoni = interaction.options.getString('reason') ?? 'No reason provided';
    
            await interaction.reply( {
                embeds: [{
                   title:  'Banned a member',
                   description:  `Banned ${target.user.username}`,
                   color: '15548997',
                   thumbnail: { 
                    url : 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1141734104543539220/1141750239984898190/TEST_BOT.jpg'
                   },

                   fields: [
                    {
                        name: "Responsible Moderator",
                        value: `<@${interaction.user.id}>`
                    },

                    {
                        name: 'Why were they banned?',
                        value:`${reasoni}` 
                    },

                    {
                        name: 'UserId',
                        value:`${target.user.id}` 
                    },
                ],

                footer: {
                    text: 'Current version: 0.0.1',
                    icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1141734104543539220/1141750630763987015/pooperson.jpg',
                },

                }]  
            });
            await interaction.guild.members.ban(target)

            if (console.error) {
                interaction.reply({content: "i cant do that.", ephemeral:true})
            }
            
            
        }
```

the code that I showed works perfectly fine (once again), but if its a admin perm/higher role then the person trying to ban, it completely crashes the bot.

as you guessed it the error in the console is "missing perms". so instead of having that "missing perms" error in my console, is there  a possible way for me to just make the bot reply with "sorry, cant do that"
or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're checking if console.error exists, which is a function used to log errors into the console and not related to what you're doing at all.

To send a message when the ban fails, you simply need to .catch the error

```
await interaction.guild.members.ban(target).then(()=>{
    await interaction.reply( {
        embeds: [{
            title:  'Banned a member',
// ...etc
                   
}).catch((err)=>{
    interaction.reply({content: "i cant do that.", ephemeral:true})
})
```

This ensures the reply only ever fires when an actual error is caught, and will prevent your code from crashing.

Comment: didnt work sadly or maybe im doing it wrong, its stil lthe same error happening. but the command still shows up in chat.

Comment: @averagediscordbotmaker does it also reply "i cant do that" or does the error happen elsewhere?

Comment: nope, the apllication failed and i get an eror

Comment: (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1141736855570751569/1142119554307338290/image.png) (vortexwraith is the server owner and doesnt actually get banned)

Comment: @averagediscordbotmaker i have updated my solution. The previous one only caused the error not to crash the code, this one should work and only respond when the user gets banned. `.then` should only activate when the ban is successful, `.catch` should only activate when an error is thrown. Just put the embed send code into the .then function.